# Custom compound control - unbound prefix, failed to instantiate

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a compound control, and set custom attributes for it.

The class for the control:

```
package hu.ppke.itk.kozcs.android.activities;

import hu.ppke.itk.kozcs.android.project.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SettingBox extends RelativeLayout {

    public SettingBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        String service = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(service);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.setting_box, this, true);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SettingBox);
        String title = a.getString(R.styleable.SettingBox_title);
        String description = a.getString(R.styleable.SettingBox_description);

        TextView titleText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView descriptionText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.description);

        titleText.setText(title);
        descriptionText.setText(description);

        a.recycle();
    }


}
```

res/values/attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="SettingBox">
        <attr name="title" format="string" />
        <attr name="description" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

layout xml for the control (setting_box.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkbox"
        android:text="@string/use_gps"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkbox"
        android:text="@string/gps_descr"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

</merge>
```

and finally the layout where i use this control (settings.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/hu.ppke.itk.kozcs.android.activities"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <hu.ppke.itk.kozcs.android.activities.SettingBox
        andrid:id="@+id/test_setting_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:description="description"
        app:title="title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Every time i save the last xml, i got this error message:
`settings.xml:9: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`

Also there is an error in the log:
`hu.ppke.itk.kozcs.android.activities.SettingBox failed to instantiate.`

What am i missing here?

Comment: in the merge tag, can you remove the space between " and > ?

Comment: Should i? Actually the code formatter put it there.

Comment: Which one is settings.xml?

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `android:id` attribute is called `andrid:id`.

```
<hu.ppke.itk.kozcs.android.activities.SettingBox
    andrid:id="@+id/test_setting_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:description="description"
    app:title="title" />
```

Comment: I can't believe it. I was googleing this error for hours. :) Thanks.